# make <div> take only content space: disable stretching

Tags: html, styles

I have a `<div>` with some nested divs. All of them have the same height. I need parent `<div>` to take so much `width` as its content takes (I want to apply `border-style` property). Property `display:inline` (for parent) doesn't help me.

Here is markup:

```
   <div style="border-style:solid;height:60px;">
        <div  style="display:inline;float:left;background-color:Aqua;height:60px;width:30px;border-left-style:solid"></div>
        <div  style="display:inline;float:left;background-color:Black;height:60px;width:30px;border-left-style:solid"></div>
        ......       
   </div>
```

Comment: could you provide us jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaMe/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block;` seems to work:

```
 <div style="display:inline-block;border-style:solid;height:60px;">
        <div  style="display:inline;float:left;background-color:Aqua;height:60px;width:30px;border-left-style:solid"></div>
        <div  style="display:inline;float:left;background-color:Black;height:60px;width:30px;border-left-style:solid"></div>
   </div>
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpzL7/1/)

Some older browsers won't support `inline-block`, so you'll need to check it in the browsers you support.

I'm assuming these styles will make their way into a stylesheet at some point, rather than being purely inline.

Comment: pretty!thanks. (this is a result markup of custom control ASP)